# K-means clustering algorithm failing even with appropriate amout of driver memory.why?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I was tying to run Apache Spark MLlib's k-means algorithm on a dataset of ~9.2GB which gave me OOME because my driver memory was only 2600mb ([How to deal with executor memory and driver memory in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181737/how-to-deal-with-executor-memory-and-driver-memory-in-spark)).

As the post suggested I increased the driver memory to 6gb and made some datasets with different sizes. The algorithm runs fine on datasets of sizes 800MB and 1.6GB but at 2.3GB it gave the same error that the 9GB one gave. Why am I still getting memory errors?

The data on the file looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5.....,2400000
1,2,3,4,5.....,2400000
1,2,3,4,5.....,2400000
.
.
.
```

The code:

```
data = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/riz/dir1/hellotwomillion.dat")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([int(x) for x in line.split(',')]))
clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 2
                    , maxIterations=10,
    runs=10, initializationMode="random")
```

*Image of failed stage*
[image: Failed stage image]

*Image of failed stage detail*
[image: Failed stage detail]

Apache Spark version 1.6.2

Number of cores 27

2.5GB memory per node.

9 workers (3 cores per worker).

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.trainKMeansModel.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 64, slave2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap(PairRDDFunctions.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.runAlgorithm(KMeans.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.run(KMeans.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainKMeansModel(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:353)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: you need find out if there are some data skew, usually it will cause oom. maybe you can filter data with some conditions

Comment: did you really say **4 million columns**??

Comment: @desertnaut yes, why? if you think explaining would be time consuming can you please link any article or something?

Comment: because... it is really a lot of columns! I suggest you re-edit the post and keep this piece of info available (preferably with bold...)